Store data inaccessible from user in Nextjs
In a Nextjs (v14.2.12 with the app router) frontend, for the authtentication I don't want to send a backend request everytime a user enters a new page. Is there a way to store the user object, that is recieved after a successful login, in a way that it is available in my middleware but the enduser in the browser must not be able to access it (so he can't change it). If possible, I do not want to have to encrypt the user object.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
